# Set Charset/Collation MySQL PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

How to set collation for MySQL Connection?

```
// Here is default/Expected output
mysqli_get_charset($con);
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'charset' => string 'utf8mb4' (length=7)
  public 'collation' => string 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' (length=18)
  public 'dir' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'min_length' => int 1
  public 'max_length' => int 4
  public 'number' => int 224
  public 'state' => int 1
  public 'comment' => string '' (length=0)

mysqli_character_set_name($con);
\tests\db.php:22:string 'utf8mb4' (length=7)
```

After setting charset using :

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');

// Output :

mysqli_get_charset($con);
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'charset' => string 'utf8mb4' (length=7)
  public 'collation' => string 'utf8mb4_general_ci' (length=18)
  public 'dir' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'min_length' => int 1
  public 'max_length' => int 4
  public 'number' => int 45
  public 'state' => int 1
  public 'comment' => string 'UTF-8 Unicode' (length=13)

mysqli_character_set_name($con);
\tests\db.php:22:string 'utf8mb4' (length=7)
```

## Tried using these :

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';");
mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';");
mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';");
```

After using `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');`

the collation resets to `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Any way to prevent this.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't care for the *client* collation.

The only use for the charset-related stuff on the client is the escaping function but it uses only charset, and don't care for the collation, which is used only on the server.

Therefore, if you need to set the specific collation, the correct code would be

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");
```

After this, both proper charset and collation will be set.

You can test it with the following code:

```
var_dump(mysqli_get_charset($con)->collation,$con->query("select @@collation_connection")->fetch_row()[0]);
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
var_dump(mysqli_get_charset($con)->collation,$con->query("select @@collation_connection")->fetch_row()[0]);
mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");
var_dump(mysqli_get_charset($con)->collation,$con->query("select @@collation_connection")->fetch_row()[0]);
```

For me it outputs

```
string(17) "latin1_swedish_ci"
string(17) "latin1_swedish_ci"
string(18) "utf8mb4_general_ci"
string(18) "utf8mb4_general_ci"
string(18) "utf8mb4_general_ci"
string(18) "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

and the last one - the **connection** collation is what you actually need.

Comment: When using mysqli_get_charset($con);, mysqli_get_charset($con)->collation shows utf8mb4_general_ci . But it should show utf8mb4_unicode_ci . See Default/Expected. Or its ok to leave utf8mb4_general_ci their.